# Why is the style different? something is missing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

[image: default field]

[image: the error looks like this (field that I created)]

I modified the code like this: ArticleRequest.php

```
  public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'slug' => 'unique:articles,slug,'.\Request::get('id'),
        'content' => 'required|min:2',
        'date' => 'required|date',
        'status' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'description'=> 'required',
    ];
}
```

ArticleCrudController.php

```
$this->crud->addField([
                'name' => 'description',
                'label' => 'Description',
                'type' => 'text',
                'placeholder' => 'Description meta tag',
                'attributes' => [
                      'required' => true,
       ],
            ]);
```

Why is the style different? something is missing?
thanks, you are very kind
Marco

Comment: What do you mean by "style is different" ?

Comment: if you look at the first two links above, you understand thanks for the help marco

Comment: There are no links above, and it's unclear from the images what difference you're looking at. Tell us specifically what's wrong. Is it the "Please fill in this field" versus "The title field is required" bit?

Comment: @MarcoZarpellon you should add validation rules for description like you did for title to get same appearance.
See answer below

Comment: I would like the style to be the same as the first link: red field border and message text with a red background

Comment: @MarcoZarpellon I don't believe you can adjust the styling of that. It's a built-in browser message triggered by the HTML5 validation attributes like `<input required>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        // you should add validation rule for description attr
        'description' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'unique:articles,slug,'.\Request::get('id'),
        'content' => 'required|min:2',
        'date' => 'required|date',
        'status' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'description'=> 'required',
    ];
}
```

Comment: it is not very clear to me can you give me an example?   'description'=> 'required'

Comment: I assume you're using Laravel Backpack, If you want to get error messages with fancy styles (red alert box) for an attribute, First you must add validation rules (required, min, max ... ) to it and Backpack will do its magic for you.

Check links below 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/crud-tutorial#the-request

Comment: I added validation but it doesn't work   'description'=> 'required|min:2|max:255

Comment: it could be a bug?